# Call a function every 5 sec angular

Tags: angularjs, time, setinterval

I need to get data from my back-end at every 5 secs, I have a http function which returns me the data, but now I need to call another function which invokes the http function on every 5 secs. I'm searching for a solution with Angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `$http` call into a function, and on complete, call it again in 5 seconds:

```
function getStuff() {
   $http.get().success(function(data) {
       $timeout(getStuff, 5000);
   });
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the deprecated `.success()` method: use `.then()` instead. Also this probably wants an error handler that schedules a new timeout even if the `$http` call failed.